# How to add SFTP filepath dynamically in Azure Logic App Workflow from Azure Functions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App workflow which takes input from `Azure Function` for `SFTP filepath`. I am able to read the file in `SFTP filepath` when I specify its path manually but the same does not work when I pass the path from Azure Function. It always returns a `404` error:

```
Error Message: 
  "status": 404,
  "message": "A reference was made to a file or folder which does not exist.\r\nclientRequestId: 20e05109-7277-4476-924b-ff69715a9134",
  "source": "sftp-logic-cp-westeurope.logic-ase-westeurope.p.azurewebsites.net"
```

Comment: Hi there! What is your end-goal? Are you able to provide a screenshot of your existing workflow?

Comment: Also, if you provide the JSON code would be helpful to better understand the issue

Comment: @amarendra-k any updates? also, which language are you using in your Azure Function?

Comment: I am using C# for Azure Function.